# Is there a way to know if IoT hub quota exceed WITHOUT data ingestion?

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub

I have below code which give me a nice exception about IoT quota exceeded while I am ingesting data to IOT hub, but does C# sdk has any method which gives me a way to find out that quota is out for a day WITH OUT data ingestion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [Iot Hub Resource - Get Quota Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iot-hub-resource/get-quota-metrics)

the following is the result of the F1-Free tier:

```
{
  "value":[
    {
      "name":"TotalMessages",
      "currentValue":101,
      "maxValue":8000
    },
    {
      "name":"TotalDeviceCount",
      "currentValue":17,
      "maxValue":500
    }
  ]
}
```